# Does Spring handle Hibernate NonUniqueObjectException?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to write a RESTful web service, with a database back-end.  My save routine is wrapped in a try/catch ...

```
private void saveData() {
   try {
      service.saveReport(xmlData);
   }
   catch(DataAccessException e) {  // Spring's DataAccessException
      throw new MyException();
   }
}
```

which works for DB errors like a unique constraint violation for instance.

But I'm getting Hibernate's NonUniqueObjectException currently, due to a bug in my code.

I'm curious however, why doesn't Spring's DataAccessException "catch" the NonUniqueObjectException?  Is there another Spring Exception which I should use (in addition to DataAccessException) to "catch" this Hibernate Exception?

Or I can certainly catch the Hibernate exception myself.  But I didn't know if Spring would/could.

UPDATE -------
My service.save(xmlData) actually does more than just "save" but first does some processing, copying the XML data into the correct (list of) @Entity beans, then looping through the Entity beans, saving each one.  The Hibernate Exception occurs during setting up the Entity beans themselves, not during the actual dao.save(entityBean).

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Your DAO neeeds to be proxied to allow for Spring automatic exception translation. Either add the @Repository annotation to your DAO or explictly configure a PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor bean post processor to your configuration

Comment: They are already.  The Service class is marked with both @Service and @ Transactional, and the DAO classes are marked with @ Repository.